# AWSDeploy to re-deploy ASP.NET WebAPI ELB application isn't working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using the Visual Studio AWS add-on/plugin to deploy my application, but want to move to a CI/CD server and scripted deployment.

I've installed the AWS SDK for Windows and thus want to use the awsdeploy.exe command line to accomplish this.

I've used msbuild and a publish profile to create the .zip deployable of my application (ASP.NET WebApi project)

I've put together the following command line command:

```
awsdeploy.exe -r -w -v -l "C:\<path_to>\deploylog.txt" "-DDeploymentPackage=C:\<path_to>\my_app.zip" "-DAWSAccessKey=<my_access_key>" "-DAWSSecretKey=<my_secret_key>" "C:\<path_do>\AWSDeployConfiguration.txt"
```

The "AWSDeployConfiguration.txt" file is what was generated by VisualStudio when I did the first deployment.

RESULT:
The console output and the text written to the log is:

```
INFO - Scanning configuration.
INFO - ...inspecting application '<my_app_name>' for environment '<my_environment_name>' and version 'v20180918223701'
```

Nothing happens with the ELB application.

What am I missing and/or how do I get more information to figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question on the AWS forums and got the following answer that also worked for me.

Hi! I have this same what You when I trying run this from `cmd`. But it You will try check what application is returning You will see that value is `3`. Generally everything `!=0` is error.

What I did?
1. I checked with `Process Monitor` if application is doing any network request to AWS - no it even not trying. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

2. I decided to recompile `awasdeploy.exe` and I found out that in the main procedure is a `try... catch..` without any logs and just `return(3)`. I added some logs and get a detailed error - look at attached image.

After few attempts I get a list of missing dll files:
AWSSDK.MobileAnalytics.dll
AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity.dll

All these files I found in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\bin` and just simply copied to: `C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\Deployment Tool` (next to `awsdeploy.exe`)

Now deploy is working again.